# for loop is giving different result than +=

Tags: c++

I really do not understand what is happening here but:

when I do:

```
colorIndex += len - stopPos;
for(int m = 0; m < len - stopPos; m++)
{
    colorUniPos++;
}
```

it does not give me the same result as doing:

```
colorIndex += len - stopPos;
colorUniPos += len - stopPos;
```

I think it becomes off by one or something. Shouldn't both of these obtain the same result?

Thanks

Comment: What are the two results that you get?  What are the types of all of the variables?  What are the values of the two variables?  What did you see when you stepped through this code in a debugger?  There is insufficient information here to answer this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This won't produce the same result if len - stopPos < 0

Answer (score 0):

This is correct if `len - stopPos` is a positive value or zero, but for negative values `colorUniPos` just keeps its value because the loop isn't executed.